# tryCatch and ggplot

Tags: r, error-handling, ggplot2, try-catch

I use `tryCatch` a lot to capture potential error messages in my R code, but I faced a strange issue today with `ggplot` - and I really do not have any idea what is going on (even after some time spent on Google/SO searching).

Simple example with an incomplete `ggplot` call (no added layer):

```
> tryCatch(eval(parse(text = 'ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=wt))')), error = function(e) e)
Error: No layers in plot
```

So the error is not captured. Even more: I get an R object with `ggplot` class:

```
> str(tryCatch(eval(parse(text = 'ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=wt))')), error = function(e) e))
List of 8
 $ data       :'data.frame':    32 obs. of  11 variables:
  ..$ mpg : num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
  ..$ cyl : num [1:32] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
  ..$ disp: num [1:32] 160 160 108 258 360 ...
  ..$ hp  : num [1:32] 110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
  ..$ drat: num [1:32] 3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
  ..$ wt  : num [1:32] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
  ..$ qsec: num [1:32] 16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
  ..$ vs  : num [1:32] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ am  : num [1:32] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ gear: num [1:32] 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
  ..$ carb: num [1:32] 4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
 $ layers     : list()
 $ scales     :Reference class 'Scales' [package "ggplot2"] with 1 fields
  ..$ scales: NULL
  ..and 20 methods, of which 9 are possibly relevant:
  ..  add, clone, find, get_scales, has_scale, initialize, input, n,
  ..  non_position_scales
 $ mapping    :List of 2
  ..$ x: symbol hp
  ..$ y: symbol wt
 $ options    :List of 1
  ..$ labels:List of 2
  .. ..$ x: chr "hp"
  .. ..$ y: chr "wt"
 $ coordinates:List of 1
  ..$ limits:List of 2
  .. ..$ x: NULL
  .. ..$ y: NULL
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "cartesian" "coord"
 $ facet      :List of 1
  ..$ shrink: logi TRUE
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "null" "facet"
 $ plot_env   :<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "ggplot"
```

Any ideas to capture these kind of errors?

---

*Update*: I am aware of the fact that the above call might be OK in some situations (like adding a layer later). But then please consider the following example (please note that we have a typo there: `t` is provided on `y` axis instead of `wt`):

```
> tryCatch(eval(parse(text = 'ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=t)) + geom_point()')), error = function(e) e)
Error in data.frame(x = c(110, 110, 93, 110, 175, 105, 245, 62, 95, 123,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 32, 0
```

I do get the error message, but that's not captured by `tryCatch`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happens because the error doesn't occur in the call to `ggplot`, but in the call to `print.ggplot`.

So your `tryCatch` works, but the error occurs only later, when trying to print. This means you have to put the `tryCatch` around the `print` statement:

Try this instead:

```
x <- tryCatch(eval(parse(text = 'ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=wt))')), 
              error = function(e) e)
tryCatch(print(x), error = function(e) e)
<simpleError: No layers in plot>
```

---

And for your second example:

```
x <- eval(parse(text = 'ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=t)) + geom_point()'))
tryCatch(print(x), error = function(e) e)

<simpleError in data.frame(x = c(110, 110, 93, 110, 175, 105, 245, 62, 95, 123, 123, 180, 180, 180, 205, 215, 230, 66, 52, 65, 97, 150, 150, 245, 175, 66, 91, 113, 264, 175, 335, 109), y = structure(function (x) standardGeneric("t"), generic = structure("t", package = "base"), package = "base", group = list(), valueClass = character(0), signature = "x", default = structure(function (x) UseMethod("t"), target = structure("ANY", class = structure("signature", package = "methods"), .Names = "x", package = "methods"), defined = structure("ANY", class = structure("signature", package = "methods"), .Names = "x", package = "methods"), generic = structure("t", package = "base"), class = structure("derivedDefaultMethod", package = "methods")), skeleton = structure(function (x) UseMethod("t"), target = structure("ANY", class = structure("signature", package = "methods"), .Names = "x", package = "methods"), defined = structure("ANY", class = structure("signature", package = "methods"), .Names = "x", package = "methods"), generic = structure("t", package = "base"), class = structure("derivedDefaultMethod", package = "methods"))(x), class = structure("standardGeneric", package = "methods")),     PANEL = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), check.names = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE): arguments imply differing number of rows: 32, 0>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! How could I miss this? :)

It was pretty obvious after taking a glance at your first line, but this question gave me a few hours of headache before that. So in short: thanks again :)