# How to use purrr::possibly to catch plot errors

Tags: r, purrr

I tried to write a function which would run other functions "safely". By safely here I just mean I don't want scripts to fall over if some plot functions fail. Simple example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)

## function I thought I could use to run other functions safely
safe_plot <- function(.FUN, ...) {
  safe_fun <- purrr::possibly(.f = .FUN, otherwise = NULL)
  safe_fun(...)
}

## Simple plot function
plot_fun <- function(df) {
  df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(xvar, yvar)) +
    geom_point()
}

## Works for good data
some_data <- data.frame(xvar = 1:10, yvar = 1:10)
safe_plot(.FUN = plot_fun, df = some_data)
```

[image: good]

```
## Works here for data that is not defined:
> safe_plot(.FUN = plot_fun, df = not_defined)
NULL

## Falls over for an empty data frame
empty_data <- data.frame()
> safe_plot(.FUN = plot_fun, df = empty_data)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'xvar' not found
```

What I would like is a generic function that I can pass plot functions to which - if an error occurs - won't stop a script. I know I could do the following for example:

```
## Simple plot function with check
plot_fun <- function(df) {
  if (nrow(df) > 0) {
    df %>%
      ggplot(aes(xvar, yvar)) +
      geom_point()
  }
}
```

But here I'm more interested in learning about why purrr::possibly did not catch the error and a perhaps a better way to go about this problem...assuming I don't care what may have caused an error.

Answer (score 0):

You could directly use `tryCatch`.
In either cases, the reason for the error not being catched by `possibly` and eventually `tryCatch` is due to the [lazy evaluation of `print.ggplot`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11782043/13513328) which occurs outside `tryCatch`.
Solution is to force `print()` into `tryCatch()`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

safe_plot <- function(.FUN, ...) {
  tryCatch(print(.FUN(...)),error = function(e) NULL)
}

## Simple plot function
plot_fun <- function(df) {
  df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(xvar, yvar)) +
    geom_point() 
}


## Works for good data
some_data <- data.frame(xvar = 1:10, yvar = 1:10)
safe_plot(.FUN = plot_fun, df = some_data)
#> NULL
```

[image]

```
empty_data <- data.frame()
safe_plot(.FUN = plot_fun, df = empty_data)
#> NULL
```

Comment: not sure why this answer doesn't seem to fullfill your needs, so that you posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67637842/13513328)