# Correct use of tryCatch to skip plot error

Tags: r

This is a follow up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67619144/how-to-use-purrrpossibly-to-catch-plot-errors) which didn't get any traction. I realise now that this has nothing to do with `purrr::possibly` specifically as `tryCatch` also doesn't work like I thought.

I'm trying to write a function which will run any other arbitrary function without throwing an error. This might not be good practice but I want to understand why this does not work:

```
library(ggplot2)

## function I thought I could use to run other functions safely
safe_plot <- function(.FUN, ...) {
  tryCatch({
    .FUN(...)
  },
  error = function(e) {
    message(e)
    print("I have got passed the error")
  })
}

## Simple plot function
plot_fun <- function(df) {
   
  ggplot(df, aes(xvar, yvar)) +
    geom_point()
}

## Works for good data
some_data <- data.frame(xvar = 1:10, yvar = 1:10)
safe_plot(.FUN = plot_fun, df = some_data)
```

[image: good]

```
## Works here for data that is not defined:
> safe_plot(.FUN = plot_fun, df = not_defined)
object 'not_defined' not found[1] " I have got passed the error"


## Falls over for an empty data frame
empty_data <- data.frame()
safe_plot(.FUN = plot_fun, df = empty_data) 

## Why does't this get past this error and print the message?
> safe_plot(.FUN = plot_fun, df = empty_data)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'xvar' not found
```

Why doesn't the last call get to the print statement? I suspect I am abusing tryCatch but I don't know why. Reading some other questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093914/use-trycatch-skip-to-next-value-of-loop-upon-error), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622777/exception-handling-in-r)) I checked for the class of what tryCatch returns:

```
> ## What is returned
> empty_data <- data.frame()
> what_is_this <- safe_plot(.FUN = plot_fun, df = empty_data)
> what_is_this
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'xvar' not found
> class(what_is_this)
[1] "gg"     "ggplot"
```

So in the plot function above `ggplot(df,`  does not fail because there is a `df` of `empty_data`. The error must occur in `aes(xar,` . But why does this not return an error class and instead returns a ggplot?